# Cannot get WPF attached property via Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, attached-properties

I have custom attached property in shared lib:

```
public class Freezable
{
    public static bool GetIsFrozen(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFrozenProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFrozen(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsFrozenProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFrozenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFrozen", typeof(bool), typeof(UIElement), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

This property was tested in code and value was successfully stored.

```
Freezable.SetIsFrozen(control, value);
var correctValue =Freezable.GetIsFrozen(control);
```

But then i am trying to get my property via Reflection. And I have exception that property cannot be find (getMethod is null and setMethod is null)!

```
 public void FindAttachedProperty(Type elementType, string propertyName)
    {
        MethodInfo getMethod = elementType.GetMethod("Get" + propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        MethodInfo setMethod = elementType.GetMethod("Set" + propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    }
```

Canvas.Left, Canvas.Right working well and without any problems. What i am doing wrong and why i cannot get my attached property!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. My best guess is that when you are calling `FindAttachedProperty` method you are giving the `System.Windows.Freezable` as elementType instead of your own implementation from library.